# Find how many motors are needed to assure continuous work.

Tags: probability

> We have a motor that has a working time that follows an
> exponential distribution $exp(\lambda)$ and has a mean for time of
> functioning of $500hours$.
>
> 1. assuming that if a motor is broken it is broken for good, find how many motors are needed to assure continuous work during a
>    $2500hours$ trip, to a degree of certainty 98%.
> 2. Assuming that if a motor takes $250hours$ to be fixed, find how many motors are needed to assure continuous work during a
>    $2500hours$ trip, to a degree of certainty 100%.

My attempt :

1.Let $\mathbf{E}_i \sim exp(\lambda)$ the R.V that maps the time of work of a motor $E_i$.

We have  $F_{\mathbf{E}_i}(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$

Let us find $\lambda$, we have : $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{E}_i)=\frac{1}{\lambda}=500$

thus $\lambda = \frac{1}{500}$

We want to find $n$ such that :
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n P(\textbf{E}_i>2500)=98\%  \\
&n P(\mathbf{E_i}>2500)=98\%  \\
&n(1-F_{\mathbf{E}_i}(2500))=98\% \\
& n e^{-2500\lambda}=98\% \\
&n=\frac{98\% }{e^{-\frac{2500}{500}}} \\
&n=145.44489...
\end{align}
$$
We thus need 146 motors.

2. We have to find the number of motors that assure work for 250 hours.

We want n such that :
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n P(\textbf{E}_i>250)=1  \\
&n P(\mathbf{E_i}>250)=1 \; \; \; \#\text{i quelconque dans \{1,$\ldots$,n\}}\\
&n(1-F_{\mathbf{E}_i}(250))=98\% \\
& n e^{-250\lambda}=1 \\
&n=\frac{1}{e^{-\frac{250}{500}}} \\
&n=1.6487...
\end{align}
$$

Thus we need 2+1=3 motors. The extra one is there because for the case where it is broken early, the other 2 motors will assure functioning for 250 hours that the first motor will take to be repaired.

Is this correct? I feel like it isn't the right to go about it, I don't know what conditions do i need exactly to assure continuous functionment with no down-time...

Comment: Are you familiar with Poisson processes? If $N$ is the number of motors that break down on $[0,2500)$, then you know $N\sim \text{Poisson}(5)$. If you bring $m$ motors with you on your trip, then ensuring continuous work is equivalent to the evemt $\{N \leq m-1\}$. You must find $m$ so that $\mathbb{P}(N\leq m-1)\geq 0.98$. This is a strategy for the first part of your question.

Comment: Hello, I was able to solve the first part using your suggestion. May I ask for further reading for how is $N$ a $Poisson$ random variable? and why is the 5 there? is it from $2500/500=5$?

Comment: Yes, the arrival rate of the poisson distribution is exactly $2500/500=5$. Here is a rigorous reasoning for this fact. For each $k\geq 1$ let $X_k$ denote the time that the $k^{\text{th}}$ motor breaks down. You're given that $X_1,X_2-X_1,X_3-X_2,... \sim \text{exp}(1/500)$. If you put $$N=\max\{k\geq 1:X_k<2500\}$$ then $N$ counts the number of motors that break down in $[0,2500)$. Try and prove on your own that $N\sim \text{Poisson}(5)$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that you can guarantee continuous workflow given any number of available motors for the second part of this question. For example, suppose you have $m=\text{one billion}$ motors available, and $N\sim \text{Poisson}(1/5)$ counts the number of motors that break down on $[0,100)$.

Comment: If $N=m$, then all available motors break down on $[0,100)$, and the earliest time at which one of these motors will be repaired is at $250$ hours. In other words, the event that $N=m$ suggests a discontinuous workflow with a lag of at least $150$ hours. This occurs with a non$-$zero probability. (Although it is astronomically small)

Comment: I learned about the connection between Poisson processes asnd exponential distributions here: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/

Comment: You're right, i mistranslated, the exercice says `à 100% près par hypothèse` which means at a certainty right close to 100%. Thanks

Comment: I'm stuck at proving that $N \sim Poisson(5)$. Can i get a hint? Am i supposed to use a certain theorem or is it a straightforward proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe your solution to the first part is correct.  What you need to find is the smallest $\ n\ $ such that
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{E}_i>2500\right)\ge0.98\ ,
$$
which will not, in general, be the same as the smallest $\ n\ $ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nP(\mathbf{E}_i>2500)\ge0.98\ .
$$
The sum of $\ n\ $ independent $\lambda$-exponentially distributed random variables has an [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) with parameters $\ n\ $ and $\ \lambda\ $:
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{E}_i\le x\right)=1-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda x)^ie^{-\lambda x}}{i!}\ .
$$
In your case you'll therefore have
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{E}_i>2500\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{5^ie^{-5}}{i!}
$$
Wolfram alpha's approximations for this are [$\ 0.968172\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-CDF%5BErlangDistribution%5B10%2C1%2F500%5D%2C2500%5D) for $\ n=10\ $  and [$\ 0.986305\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-CDF%5BErlangDistribution%5B11%2C1%2F500%5D%2C2500%5D) for $\ n=11\ $.  So the number of motors you need in the first case is $11$.

Note that the right-hand side of the above equation is just the formula for $\ P(N\le n-1)\ $ where $\ N\sim\text{Poisson}(5)\ $, so this is exactly the same answer that you'll get by using the method suggested in the comment.